# problems with slow pocessor laptop

Tags: installation, drivers, ati, video

There is something that bothers me a lot a it-s that: I have an Compaq Presario CQ43 172LA, this PC works with an 1.5GHZ AMD E/240 and AMD HD 6310 APU and 1.6 DDR3 ram memory. By default it came with Win 7 starter pre-installed, I changed that and installed Windows Home Premium. With Windows 7 Starter I could play HD videos even blue ray rip movies but lately I couldn't then my hdd stop working.

When I bought another I thought to download and install a linux distro and decided that should be Ubuntu because I had another PC with it and I hadn't problems with it, the 9.10 one to be precise. Once installed  (Ubuntu 12.10) I decided to watch one of my favorite movies, right now "the Avengers", in brrip and I noticed I couldn't. I installed all the codecs and privatives drivers necessary and followed some tutorials and nothing.

I installed fuduntu once before my hard disk crashed and I did I could watch my movies.

So please someone tell me why can't I watch HD movies and movies if I used to do it with Win 7 which is heavier?.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing proprietary drivers for your system.

Click the Ubuntu Dash button and type in "Software Updater" and open it, then once it loads click "Settings", and visit the "Additional Drivers" tab and select the fglrx proprietary driver, the third option, then click the "Apply Changes" button and wait for it to finish updating.

You may need to reboot, and then try running a HD video.